# PHP How can I do multiple where conditions?

Tags: php, where-clause

This is my current code for taking a user log in:

```
<?php
$uName = "";
$uNameMsg = "";
$pWord = "";
$pWordMsg = "";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $uName = $_POST["username"];
    if (empty($uName)) {
        $uNameMsg = "please enter a username<br/>";
    }

    $pWord = $_POST["password"];
    if (empty($pWord)) {
        $pWordMsg = "please enter a password<br/>";
    }
}

?>

//form goes here

<?php
    require_once("conn.php");
    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers
            WHERE username = $uName 
            AND password = $pWord";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
    or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) < 1) {
        echo "invalid username and password";
    } else {
        echo "query success, redirect header goes here";
    }
?>
```

I get a syntax error saying that the 'AND password =' clause is wrong. and then it is saying that the error is located at line 3, my  tag, while the 'AND password ='is in line 75.

this is the start of my code from line 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Customer Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customerlogin.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Share the code that is appear in line number 3. Also change your query like this `$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers WHERE username = '$uName ' AND password = '$pWord'";`

Comment: @Karthikeyani its just my <head> tag. ill edit.

Comment: oh ok. Did you tried the code?

Comment: Try this `SELECT username, password FROM customers WHERE username = '{$uName}'  AND password = '{$pWord}'"`

Comment: FYI, putting user input directly into your SQL statement is *extremely* risky due to SQL injection vulnerability.  Much better to use prepared statements and bind your variables.

Comment: @SgtAJ yup i understand. i plan to use mysqli_escape_string() after i finalize the workign functions. im just not using it right now for simplicty

Comment: @nanjero05: Escaping has been proven to be an inefficient solution.  You should use prepared statements as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this.This definitely gonna work:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers
            WHERE username = '$uName' 
            AND password = '$pWord'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable string concatenation is wrong in the SQL statement try the bellow one instead of your query code line

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers
            WHERE username = '".$uName." '
            AND password = '".$pWord."'";
```

Comment: The single quotes should be inside the double quotes, not the other way around.

Comment: When you use php variable inside the double quote you don't need to concatenate. You can simple pass the variable. For **eg :** `"Some text $variableName"`. You can use concatenation only if you are using single quote. **For eg :** `'Some text ' . $variableName . ' some text '`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers WHERE username = '$uName ' AND password = '$pWord'";
```

When you pass string value you should cover with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You missed quote `'`  around the values. You can use only numbers without quotes as values strings should be quoted. Your query is vulnerable to sql enjection so either escape your fields or use pdo. See below code for escaping the fields.

```
$pWord = $conn->real_escape_string($pWord);
$uName = $conn->real_escape_string($uName);
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers
        WHERE username = '$uName'
        AND password = '$pWord'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your query in php as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM customers 
        WHERE username = '{$uName}'  
        AND password = '{$pWord}'";
```

I assume username is a string,so it needs to be passed as string using `''`